# How to reset sonarqube password when running on localhost:9000

Tags: sonarqube

I have installed and ran sonarqube locally previously on localhost:9000 and then the login page comes for that, then i had changed the password for it previously it was username:admin and password:admin
I now have changed the password and forgot it.
I need to know how to reset it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18209054/how-to-recover-admin-password-for-sonarqube might help